# Creating a rolling three year average new variable in my R dataset?

Tags: r, statistics

I need to do a term paper with R (never did it before) and I have the following problem that I cannot solve.

I have a dataset with all countries of all years since 1950 (so one row (observation) is one country in one year, the next row is the same country one year later and so on). Now I need to construct a new variable, which is filled with the average value of the previous three years of a given variable.

Specifically it is about the democracy level of a country. So I have the variable of the democracy level of  a country for a year T, and I need a new variable, which indicates the "democracy growth" of the previous three years T(-3,0).

How can I construct this new variable?

[image]

As I said I never used R before, but I need to use `mutate()` and then I need to address year-3, year-2, year-1 and divide it by 3. But how to I address the previous three years? `Case_when` or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - How to make a mean/average of n previous values, excluding current observation (rolling average)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529825/r-how-to-make-a-mean-average-of-n-previous-values-excluding-current-observati)

Comment: Provide example data and expected output. Read about lead/lag, rolling mean.